# How can I display all of them in a single line using css?

Tags: html, css

How can I display all of them in a single line using csss.

```
        <div id="paperbusiness">
            <span id="paper">paper</span>
            <span id="business"> business</span>
        </div>

        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="yahoo.com">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="googlr.com">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="gmail.com">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="testing.php">TESTING</a></li>
                <li><a href="Req.pph">REQUIREMENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I need something like

paper business                      PORTFOLIO SERVICES ABOUT TESTING REQUIREMENTS

Comment: -1 This has been asked 1000000000 times here and on the internet in general. Try the search terms horizontal nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display: inline;
```

is all you need

Answer (score 7):

```
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

And then apply any other styling you wish.

Answer (score 0):

First make div and nav inline-block, then li as inline:

```
div, nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually display: inline-block; is much better or am I missing something?

Comment: inline-block support is incomplete in IE version 7 and below.

Comment: "or am I missing something" yup I was missing that